# Task resume not completing before function returns

Tags: ios, swift

In this code below, I have a function that calls a task to fetch the student locations. The line before task initialization gets executed, but the task itself doesn't seem to be executing. It looks to me like the next line in the function is getting executed even before task is complete. So I tried two things

1. Adding a completion handler and that didn't seem to help.
2. Adding a big for loop after task.resume() and it looks like the task was complete in one or two cases. But this doesn't look like the right thing to do.

Can someone explain if this is another thread and how to make the function wait for that thread to be complete ? I would be curious to see if there is a way to make this work and also if there is a better way to do this. Thanks a lot.

```
func getStudentLocation(completionHandler: (studentDictionary: NSDictionary) -> ()) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://parse.udacity.com/parse/classes/StudentLocation")!)
    request.addValue("QrX47CA9cyuGewLdsL7o5Eb8iug6Em8ye0dnAbIr", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue("QuWThTdiRmTux3YaDseUSEpUKo7aBYM737yKd4gY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    print("starting task")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
        print("getStudentLocation in task: \(error) \(response)")
        if error != nil { // Handle error...
            print(" error in get student location: \(error)")
            return             
        }

        let parsedResult: AnyObject
        do {
            parsedResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
        }
        catch {
            return
        }
        self.studentDictionary = parsedResult["results"] as? [String: AnyObject]
       // completionHandler(studentDictionary: self.studentDictionary!)      
       print("STudent Dictonary: \(self.studentDictionary)")
    }

    task.resume()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    getStudentLocation{
        studentDictionary in
        //studentDictionary.count
        print("Count: \(studentDictionary.count)")
    }
    return studentDictionary!.count
 }
```

Comment: `dataTaskWithRequest` is an async operation, when you submit a task it return immediately while in the background queue the task will advance and when it completes, the completion block is executed. You need to reload table after parsing and setting the datasource.

Comment: Also `parsedResult["results"] as? [String: AnyObject]` is `nil` as it is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The `dataTaskWithRequest()` runs in background. That's why your function returns immediately after `task.resume()`.

To display the downloaded data in you `tableView`, you have to reload its data at the end of the `task`'s completion handler. Right after `self.studentDictionary = parsedResult["results"] as? [String: AnyObject]`